# Halstead metrics with Sonar Qube

Tags: metrics, sonarqube

I'm using Sonar Qube and Sonar Runner. How can I calculate Halstead metrics with Sonar Qube? I googled this but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they're not computed and won't be because we find them irrelevant.

Comment: And what can I do in this situation?

Comment: Find a tool that computes them or switch to more valuable metrics computed by SonarQube such as technical debt.

Comment: What do you means? What is "technical debt"?

Comment: @DavidRACODON-QAConsultant Is there any empirical evidence that Halstead metrics are less valuable compared to some other metrics?

Comment: @eremelis you can use the Understand Software from Scitools it computes the Halstead volume